Was it ever explained why The Pagemaster (1994) had so many actors from Star Trek in it?
The 1994 film The Pagemaster cast the voices of a rather large number of actors then famous for their work on Star Trek, including Leonard Nimoy, Patrick Stewart, Whoopi Goldberg, and Christopher Lloyd. Robert Picardo and Ed Begley, Jr. were also part of the cast but joined Star Trek as part of Voyager, which started in 1995, and so were not yet known as Star Trek actors. I remember this film coming out in theaters when I was a child and I was struck by the sheer number of Star Trek voices I heard that I wondered if the film was trying to be a "Wannabe Star Trek".
Was it ever explained why this film cast so many actors from Star Trek?

Was the casting of Star Trek actors intentional in order to attract existing Star Trek fans to this film?
Was this due to re-use of the same casting companies, etc., between this film and the various Star Trek incarnations?
Was this due to pure chance?


Was Christopher Lloyd in Star Trek? At the very least, I imagine it's not the role that comes to mind for most people when they think of him.

@F1Krazy he was commander kruge, main antagonist of star trek 3. From my understanding, it was the first theatrical voice over role for most of the trek-related cast, so probably just friends hiring friends and buddies, rather than anything trek-related by itself

Hmm. Lots of American films have Star Trek actors. It was a large ensemble cast, ran for decades and was successful.

I'd say Gargoyles had more TNG actors
